# How do I use sprintf to add padding zeroes on the right in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to pad zeroes to the right side of a given number using `sprintf`.

Example: if the number is `0715` then I want to pad zeroes to the right side creating a new six-digit number:

```
Input-->0715
Output-->071500
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it using `substr`. Append six `0`s and get the string from `0th` to `6th` index. But obviously as Sobrique said you can't do it treating it as number.

```
my $num = '0715';
print substr $num.'0'x6,0,6;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my $num='0715';
$num.='0'x( 6 - length $num);
print $num;
```

Comment: Use of uninitialized value $fixed_length in subtraction (-) at test.pl line 4.

Comment: @reenadevi `*` not repeat the string. Use `x` for repeat the string.

Answer (score 3):

There is no pattern for `sprintf` to format a string left-justified with zeroes instead of spaces.

These are all the flags that [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) lists:

> ```
> space   prefix non-negative number with a space
> +       prefix non-negative number with a plus sign
> -       left-justify within the field
> 0       use zeros, not spaces, to right-justify
> #       ensure the leading "0" for any octal,
>         prefix non-zero hexadecimal with "0x" or "0X",
>         prefix non-zero binary with "0b" or "0B"
> ```

If you insist on using `sprintf`, you will have to go with `-` to *left-justify within the field*, which will give you blank spaces on the right. Then you need to change those to zeroes. You can do that with the [`tr` transliteration operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html). I'm using the shorter form with the `/r` modifier that makes `tr///` return the value instead of just changing the lvalue `$foo`.

```
my $foo = '0715';
print sprintf('%-6s', $foo) =~ tr/ /0/r;
```

**Output:**

```
071500
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with `sprintf` because if you do, then you're changing the value of the number presented — that's not formatting. Neither can you do this if you treat your number as a numeric value.

You need to test the length of your number as a string, and append zeros:

```
my $num_str = "0715";
my $length  = 6 - length($num_str);
print $num_str , "0" x $length;
```

Comment: Actually you just cannot do it with `sprintf` at all. Not because it would change the value, but because that feature doesn't exist in `sprintf`.

Comment: Well, yes. But I don't think there's any string formatting options that change the actual value of the resultant string. (Beyond rounding).

Answer (score 1):

As we all know, you can do this for the left easily with just: `print(sprintf("%010s", "hello!"));` to get `0000hello!`.  Why not use the process just a little further?  Here is one more method to do this with `sprintf()` within perl -- just make use of the appropriate `scalar()` and `reverse()` calls, and you should be all good:

[**Full Working Sandbox Demo**](https://ideone.com/mZYsjD)

Set the number and our pad length :

```
my $var = "0715";
my $padlength = 6;
```

Reverse the string, sprintf format it, and reverse it back :

```
my $formatted = reverse(sprintf("%0" . $padlength . "s", scalar(reverse($var))));
print($formatted);
```

The results are satisfactory:

```
071500
```